# Google apps script in HTML

Tags: node.js, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-api

Is it possible to use google apps script in my HTML? I want to be able to write to a spreadsheet from a form in purely Javascript from an external framework such as Node.js.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/

Comment: If your question is about accessing Google Apps Script from node.js, then it should be more explicit. Add some more info to make it clear exactly what you are asking, please.

Comment: Clarified. I'm guessing the answer is no, then? Google Apps Script is its own standalone service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Apps Script's syntax is Javascript, however it is a unique server-side framework that does not behave as a library to applications outside of the Apps Script servers. (No, you won't be able to use Google Apps Script in your node.js app.)

However, that doesn't mean that your node.js app (or any other app on the web) can't interact with your spreadsheet. For instance, your app could authenticate as you using the OAuth API, then access the spreadsheet through the Google Drive API. For an example of this, see [Accessing Google Spreadsheets from Node.js](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2014/03/04/accessing-google-spreadsheets-from-node-js/)

Alternatively, you could roll your own spreadsheet API in Google Apps Script, to support read / write of your sheet via HTTP requests from your node.js app. There are plenty of examples of that, for example [Insert new rows into Google Spreadsheet via cURL/PHP - HOW?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17860449/insert-new-rows-into-google-spreadsheet-via-curl-php-how/17871352#17871352).

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. You can use [HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) to create your web form, then send the submission data to your Spreadsheet with [server functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication).

Comment: So I can presumably embed some code in the HTML (of a Node.js app) and send the data to the Spreadsheet? I can't seem to get an instance of SpreadsheetApp.

Comment: Mogsdad comment on your post is right, did you even read the documentation on HTML Service?  The whole thing is based on interactions between client HTML/JavaScript and Google server services...

Comment: You can call server side functions using
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
    function(obj){
      alert('Returned '+obj);
    }
  ).myFunction(args);

I use them all the time

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you could use the [Google Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api) to call your Google Apps Script code from other platforms like Node.js, actually the official docs include a [quickstart for Node.js](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/quickstart/nodejs).

Answer (score -1):

You can you use HtmlService, but maybe can be helpfull to read the Google Hosted Libraries https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/

To use a Javascrtip library inside GAS, I recommend JQuery.

But Maybe, you can use Node.js inside your external website and make a AJAX Request (get or post) to a GAS and return from GAS this:

```
ContentService.createTextOutput(e.parameter.callback + "("+Utilities.jsonStringify(JSONDATA)+")").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
```

After that, process it inside your AJAX request...

Answer (score -1):

Mogsad is right that you might be better of with Google Drive API to interact with your Spreadsheet!
...But depending on your exact need you might have some possible interaction between external service and google apps scrip using **Content service** [Google Dev link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/).

Content Service can send back several information upon GET request  (ATOM, CSV, ICAL, JAVASCRIPT, JSON, RSS, TEXT, VCARD, XML). By playing around with url parameters you can get information out and in a spreadsheet, send an email, trigger some action etc!.

But that is far from a real external library and direct interaction with server side functions!