# Save form data to a PUBLIC Google Spreadsheet with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I found [the following](https://wiki.base22.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=72942000) Javascript.
It will post form data to a specific public Google Spreadsheet.

```
function postToGoogle() {
    var field1 = $("input[type='radio'][name='qs1']:checked").val();
    var field2 = $("input[type='radio'][name='qs2']:checked").val();
    var field3 = $('#feed').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/FORM_KEY/formResponse",
        data: {
            "entry.1023121230": field3, 
            "entry.1230072460": field1, 
            "entry.2113237615": field2
        },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        statusCode: {
            0: function() {
                //Success message
            },
            200: function() {
                //Success Message
            }
        }
    });
```

I would like to do the same in PHP, since Javascript can be disabled in the browser. But all PHP scripts I found online use the ZEND library and require to input my Google username and password. They seem overly complicated compared to the above Javascript. Maybe someone can rewrite the above code in PHP?

I am not a programmer, so I am not familiar with what can or can't be done.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert new rows into Google Spreadsheet via cURL/PHP - HOW?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17860449/insert-new-rows-into-google-spreadsheet-via-curl-php-how)