# How to make a query to Google Sheets API without refreshing OAuth 2.0 user token?

Tags: oauth, google-sheets-api

My task is to use Google Sheets API method `spreadsheets.values.append` the easiest way possible.

This method requires OAuth 2.0, but can I  make some kind of persistent token just for myself if I'm not gonna publish this app?
Or, is this any "proxy-api" that allows to use that method just with their persistent key (like API key in case of Google Sheets API)?

Comment: How about using Service account?

Comment: @Tanaike but I'll have to renew access token anyway

Comment: I apologize my comment was not useful for your situation.

Comment: [That answer helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17871352/9358689)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a Service Account [authorized with an API Key](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing#APIKey), NOT using OAuth.  The API key is persistent, so you don't need to refresh it.

In using this method, the service account owns the Sheets Doc, so you'll also need Drive API access to give permissions/ownership to someone else, assuming you want to do that.

Comment: API key is not enough for "spreadsheets.values.append". You need OAuth 2.0 if you're using this method through API.

Comment: @BanterFace Why would you need OAuth for that method in particular?  I don't see anything in the documentation that says that: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append

If you're talking about Authorization Scopes mentioned in the documentation, I'm using the BatchUpdate method with an API Key and it works just fine.